# How to automatically generate number_format according to the values of the function php?

Tags: php

I have the following theory of creating a function that allows you to add format to the numbers automatically according to the currency.

```
$price = 19999;
$curr = 'EUR';
function DinersFormat($price, $curr){
    $currencies['EUR'] = array(2, ',', '.');        // Euro
    $currencies['ESP'] = array(2, ',', '.');        // Euro
    $currencies['USD'] = array(2, '.', ',');        // US Dollar
    $currencies['COP'] = array(2, ',', '.');        // Colombian Peso
    $currencies['CLP'] = array(0,  '', '.');        //  Chilean Peso
}
```

It looks elegant, apart from being a good alternative to the `money_format()` function or the `NumberFormatter` function

So my idea is to be able to send the type of format to the function `number_format()` for example: [execute demo online](https://ideone.com/G0jZPG)

```
$price = 1000;
$curr = "0, ',', ' '";

$money = number_format($price, $curr);
//$money = number_format($number, 0, ',', ' ')

echo $money;
```

But the result is not correct `1,000` And the error message:

> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in /home/NC7DpL/prog.php on line 6 -> `$money = number_format($price, $curr);`

The correct output that was expected was `1 000`

Then how could I generate the `number_format()` from the arrays inside the function, so that I can then use it in its use in this way `DinersFormat($price, $curr);` or in this way `DinersFormat($price, $curr='EUR');`

Comment: I think you were looking for the splat operator: https://ideone.com/qljHOx

Comment: @J.Mick I find it interesting, even the example, although poorly formed, a little curious your question.

Comment: @IniDesing.com I admire your excitement, but you do not need to commend every single comment or answer. This is what the upvote arrows are for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way round this would be to use the [argument unpacking](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) operator (...) and pass in the array you have as in the `DinersFormat` function...

```
$price = 1000;
$curr = array(2, ',', '.');

$money = number_format($price, ...$curr);
echo $money;
```

gives

```
1.000,00
```

To include this into the function you could do something like...

```
function DinersFormat($price, $curr){
    // Array of formats against the currency
    $currencies = ['EUR' => array(2, ',', '.'),        // Euro
                'ESP' => array(2, ',', '.'),        // Euro
                'USD' => array(2, '.', ','),        // US Dollar
                'COP' => array(2, ',', '.'),        // Colombian Peso
                'CLP' => array(0,  '', '.')];        //  Chilean Peso

    return number_format($price, ...$currencies[$curr]);
}

$price = 1000;
$curr = 'EUR';
$money = DinersFormat($price,$curr);
echo $money;
```

Comment: @NigelRen Friend the arrays of the different currencies must be out of the function or as I say to the function which type format to choose. https://ideone.com/jPVzrM